# how to get one comma separated row from multiple rows in oracle without changing the order

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I have a table which contains data as following:

```
Orange
Apple
PineApple
Grapes
```

The final output that I want is: `Orange,Apple,PineApple,Grapes`

I cannot use `LISTAGG` function because I **do not want to change the order** in which the data occurs.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: `listagg()` allows you to specify an `order by`

Comment: The data occurs in some order? What does this mean? Tables contain unordered data. So, is there a column that specifies some order (e.g. a date)?

Comment: The data stored in this table forms the columns that is going to be used in another insert into table(column1(=Orange),column2(=Apple),column3(=Pineapple),column4(=Grapes))....Thats why the order cannot be changed

Comment: The data is not stored in any order, so you can't preserve that (non-existing) "order".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You can if the query is processing rows generated within a sub-query which has had an order applied to it.

Comment: @MT0: then you are preserving the order of a query, not the "order" in which rows are stored.

Comment: @vikky: This doesn't answer my question. Why is it that you think 'Orange' must come first? There seems to be nothing to indicate this. If you want to insert a row into another table with the values 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Grapes', then why don't you use a values clause? Why do you want to use above table at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LISTAGG` and order by `ROWNUM` to preserve an existing order:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( value, order_index ) AS
SELECT 'Orange',    1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Apple',     2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PineApple', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Grapes',    4 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
WITH pre_ordered_values ( value ) AS (
  SELECT value FROM your_table ORDER BY order_index
)
SELECT LISTAGG( value, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS aggregated_values
FROM   pre_ordered_values
```

**Output**:

```
| AGGREGATED_VALUES             |
| :---------------------------- |
| Orange,Apple,PineApple,Grapes |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=58d1b2ce66b7da44795d8e1b068947a8)*

*(Note: rows from a table are retrieved in a non-deterministic order and changing the data in the table, restoring a table from backups or enabling row-movement can change the order Oracle will return rows. If you require a ordering then this will have to be applied to the data rather than assuming an implicit order in which the rows will be generated.)*